# X11 MATLAB Display Figure

Tags: matlab, ssh, matlab-figure, forwarding, x11-forwarding

I know it's possible to forward any output from a remote machine to a local one by using the *X11 forwarding remote tunnelling*, so that when you run a MATLAB command it will display all the graphical outputs back to the machine you've connected from.

My question is:

Is there any MATLAB command to just output the figures (e.g., plot,surf,etc.) without displaying any other graphical object (i.e., the main interface)?

In practice, I would like to interact with MATLAB by using the command line (as shown below) and forward back only the figures.

[image]

Comment: Without MATLAB GUI around the figure? No. You can use `save` to save the figure to any desired file format and display those using your favourite visualising package though.

Comment: I am fairly certain that the option `-nodesktop` does that. I.e. when opening matlab use `matlab -nodesktop` instead of `matlab`.

Comment: With "main interface" do you mean the MATLAB command-line, editor, current folder, workspace etc GUI, or the figure-GUI itself? Because in case you want the former, `-nodesktop` should indeed work, as @NickyMattsson mentioned, otherwise the answer is no, as I outlined below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB cannot display figures without its own figure-GUI, so the answer to your question would be **no**.

However: there is a workaround: create an invisible figure using `f=figure('visible', 'off')`, then plot your data, and finally use `saveas(f,filename,fileextention)`. Don't forget to `close(f)` your figure after saving, to free the RAM. You'll now have a figure in your file directory, which you can display using your favourite visualising tool, which might even be possible through a call to [`system`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html), although I have never tested that.

Comment: Well, your answer seems to be the one I found around the web but the only workaround available at the moment. Thanks.